# Apple Push Notifications - put data into app

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to put additional data into the APN payload and read this in the app after launching?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a JSON dictionary.

```
{
"aps":
    {"alert":"test",
    "badge":1,
    "sound":"default"
    },
"Value1":info,
"Value2":3,
  "myDict":
   {
     "key1":"val1",
     "key2":val2
   }
}
```

And to access :

```
- (void)receivedRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

NSDictionnary *myDict = [userInfo valueForKeyPath:@"aps.myDict"];

}
```

Comment: And how can i access this json-dict from the app?

Comment: In the method `receivedRemoteNotification` !